# How to show there exist a solution?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, proof-explanation

Show that there exists a real number between $0≤x≤2$ so that $$x^7+8x^2−10=0$$

I know that a solution exists and its approx 1.04 but how do I show it?

Comment: $f(0)$ is negative and $f(2)$ is positive.

Comment: Hint: intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Polynomial functions are continuous

Comment: You draw a table of variations, since there is $x^2$ only going just to $f''$ is enough to determine intervals where $f'$ has zeros and further where $f$ is $\nearrow$ and $\searrow$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove like that:

Since $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(0)\cdot f(2) < 0$, then the Bolzano's Theorem (Intermediate Value Theorem) confirms that there is a root in this interval.

Answer (score 0):

ohh I get it now:
I use  this part of the intermediatiate value theorem $$x < y, f(x) = a ≤ c ≤ b = f(y) $$

Then  there  exists $$x≤s≤y$$ such that $$f(s)=C$$